# migrated wordpress site not running properly, on Ubuntu localhost?

Tags: migration

Hellos friends,

I have migrated wordpress site, when i run this on my Ubuntu local host the Home page running but other pages like blog,contact-us,services these pages not running,when i click on it then it shows me the given error

---

Not Found

The requested URL /wordpress-4.7/wordpress/about-us/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

---

this type of error message has been display
i have using Ubuntu 16.04 Os 
In wordpress dashboard the pages are available but it is not running.
Any solution please share. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps.

1) add WP_HOME or WP_SITEURL in wp-config.php example bellow.

```
// for who are using virtualhost    
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.fmt');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.fmt');
```

if use localhost

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/yoursite');
```

2) check .htaccess file. If you have no .htaccess file in your directory add the following code in the .htaccess in root folder in your site.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

3) enable mod_rewrite for php in ubuntu

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
change near <Directory /var/www/>
AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All
sudo service apache2 restart
```

4)  See debug log. If any permission related issue occur, this will let you know

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

5) Keep folder permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/yourwebsiteroot
```

Note: always try to use virtualhost.

Comment: chmod 777. Realy?

Comment: @Stephen it's localhost... so no problem but better 755 or 644
When everything works fine he can change his permission. I don't think its big matter. anyways I hope first few steps will solve his problem.